# Java Web - SSO on Intranet and FORM or BASIC on Internet

Tags: java, jboss, single-sign-on, spnego

I am looking for a SSO (Single Sign-On) framework for authentication.

My scenario is:

- JBoss 7 + Debian
- SSO with Windows 2008 Active Directory
- SSO when on Intranet
- BASIC or FORM or other when over Internet or mobile

Anyone know any framework for these needs?

I am researching two weeks and found:

- JBoss Negotiation + SPNEGO (Kerberos) (does not have support for NTLM, so can't be used over Internet)
- Waffle: not 100% Java
- jCIFS (no support for NTLMv2)

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you have looked at but these might help. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Authentication_Service    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_single_sign-on_implementations

Comment: another option is Jespa, it support NTLMv2: https://www.ioplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

If I have to do it I will have a look at Picketlink (http://www.jboss.org/picketlink/) and AD federation service.

Picketlink is the JBoss project tackling the identity management issues, including support of SAML protocol that is support by AD via its Federation Service (WS-trust may also be an option).

This way the use of open standard SAML you will have a solution that is made for the new cloud environment.

There is a document to put these tow element to getter: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigurePicketlinkOnJbossWithMicrosoftADFSV2